# How to replace text in last 20 lines of a text file?

Tags: batch-file

```
@ECHO OFF & SETLOCAL
copy /Y C:\LOG.DIR LOG.DIR
set "old=INACTIVE"
set "new=ACTIVE"
FOR /f %%a IN ('^<log.DIR find /v /c ""') DO SET /a length=%%a
SET /a length-=20
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
<log.DIR  (
FOR /l %%a IN (1,1,%length%) DO (
    SET "line="
    SET /p "line="
    ECHO !line!
))>newfile
ENDLOCAL
for /f "skip=%length% delims=" %%a in (LOG.DIR) do (
    set "str=%%a"
    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    set "str=!str:%old%=%new%!"
    >>newfile ECHO !str!
    endlocal
)
```

I just want to change last 20 lines from *INACTIVE* to *ACTIVE*. And if file has less than 20 lines, all lines of file should be changed.

But currently the new file is empty, if the number of lines in file is less than 20.

What to change to avoid an empty new file?

Comment: You are removing the last 20 lines of the file, and the question does not explain why. Obviously if the file have less than 20 lines you will end with an empty file. Can you explain why the code behaves this way or what is the purpose of the code?

Comment: i just wanna change last 20 line to ACTIVE and if it is less than 20 every rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off 
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    copy /y c:\log.dir log.dir

    set "old=INACTIVE"
    set "new=ACTIVE"

    for /f %%a in ('^<log.dir find /v /c ""') do set /a "length=%%a"

    if %length% gtr 20 ( set /a "startPoint=length-20+1" ) else ( set "startPoint=1" )

    <log.dir (
        for /l %%a in (1,1,%length%) do (
            set "line="
            set /p "line="
            if not defined line (
                echo(
            ) else if %%a lss %startPoint% (
                echo(!line!
            ) else (
                echo(!line:%old%=%new%!
            )
        )
    )>newfile

    endlocal
```

Adjust where to start depending of the file length. If you have more than 20 lines, the starting point is calculated. If you have less lines, process from the start.